# Should I restart node to update cached views when content from external api changes

Tags: node.js, caching, restart

I have a node app running my blog and my content is coming from an outside api. I use `express` and currently with `dust` templates and by default views are cached. However apparently there is no way to clear the cached files without restarting node.

Is it normal that when I update a blogpost I restart node or am I doing something wrong?

I have a webhook, so I can act on the content change, I just don't know what I would correctly do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your blog post are stored inside a database, express will only cache you html template but will populate your views with the information.
if your blogposts are new ht;l page each time, I think you will need to restart your nodejs server. But in your express configuration (template configuration I think) you have an option to deactivate the cache.
And/Or you can use pm2 or nodemon to restart your nodejs on every changes (not really the best way)

PS: oups talk to much about different way, forget you have the content from an API. So I think you can remove your cache on dust. The only time I restart nodejs is when I update the javascript/nodejs code.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I see view caching in general as pretty beneficial so deactivating it does not sound so good to me.

It sounds a little like I am doing my templates wrong, if you say that it should only store html and not the content.

From PHP I am used to just replacing a cached view, so this concept does not really exist in node?

Comment: I never used dust, so I'm not sure how it handle caching. But using ejs, or swig or other, they just cache the full html and all params inside your template should be replace with the value you send fron your route/controller to your template engine

Comment: Thanks, I actually had an issue where the content was cached somewhere else. The cache behaviour you describe is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you will need to restart the server but modify your express configurations to disable the view caching in the future. 
simply you can add something like that:

```
var app = express();
app.disable('view cache'); //app: is express
```